# Where to get Fastdebug/Debug build of JDK 8 for Windows?

Tags: java-8, java

I want to get a JDK 8 that was built with debug or fastedebug option to investigate a low-level performance-related problem. To be more specific, I want a JDK 8 64-bit build for Windows that supports `-XX:+PrintMethodData` option.

However I can't find any public debug-enabled JDK build for Windows. Is my only option to take OpenJDK and build it myself?

PS: I don't need a production quality JDK. I just want to get more info from JIT.

PS2: Related links:

https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds - OpenJDK. Only JDK 6 and 7.
https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild - OpenJDK 8 but no debug versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I can't find any public debug-enabled JDK build for Windows.

I added "fastdebug" binaries that match latest "ojdkbuild" release:

- direct download: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases/download/1.8.0.111-1/java-1.8.0-openjdk-fastdebug-1.8.0.111-1.b15.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64.zip
- sha256: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases/download/1.8.0.111-1/java-1.8.0-openjdk-fastdebug-1.8.0.111-1.b15.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64.zip.sha256

Debuginfo there is zipped in `.diz` files in `jre/bin` and `jre/bin/server` directories.

Debug binaries are planned for following "ojdkbuild" builds, but not yet implemented in build scripts, see: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/issues/7 , if you'll have any specific requirements about debug symbols - I will appreciate comments there.

> Is my only option to take OpenJDK and build it myself?

Building vanilla OpenJDK 8 for Windows is relatively easy, just note that it supports only VS2010 (SDK 7.1) toolchain.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Any plans to mention this build on https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/ ? Actually I've already built the JDK from source myself a day ago but spend about a day to setup toolchain and solve related issues. Unfortunately build instructions for JDK seem a bit outdated and miss some points.

Comment: Anyway, I think this build will be useful for other developers. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexeiOsipov , going to announce debug builds eventually, but not now - want to integrate them into main builds process first (some cleanup is required for that)